# How to append nodes of one xml to another xml using xPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <Product>Product Name 1</Product>
            <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
            <SampleID>1</SampleID>
            <LineNo>Line1</LineNo>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Product>Product Name 2</Product>
            <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
            <SampleID>2</SampleID>
            <LineNo>Line2</LineNo>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Product>Product Name 3</Product>
            <EmployeeID>1234567</EmployeeID>
            <SampleID>3</SampleID>
            <LineNo>Line3</LineNo>
        </Row>
   </Rowset>
 </Rowsets>
```

and another XML file like :

```
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <Prod_Shift>1</Prod_Shift>
            <Target>2</Target>
            <FileName>FileName</FileName>
        </Row>
     </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now, for every "Row" node in the first XML, I need to append the contents of second XML.

And after appending the second XML on the first, the first XML should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <Product>Product Name 1</Product>
            <EmployeeID>12345</EmployeeID>
            <SampleID>1</SampleID>
            <LineNo>Line1</LineNo>
            <Prod_Shift>1</Prod_Shift>
            <Target>2</Target>
            <FileName>FileName</FileName>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Product>Product Name 2</Product>
            <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
            <SampleID>2</SampleID>
            <LineNo>Line2</LineNo>
            <Prod_Shift>1</Prod_Shift>
            <Target>2</Target>
            <FileName>FileName</FileName>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Product>Product Name 3</Product>
            <EmployeeID>1234567</EmployeeID>
            <SampleID>3</SampleID>
            <LineNo>Line3</LineNo>
            <Prod_Shift>1</Prod_Shift>
            <Target>2</Target>
            <FileName>FileName</FileName>
        </Row>
   </Rowset>
 </Rowsets>
```

I'm new to xPath.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: XPath alone can't do that, you need to use XSLT or XQuery or any language like C#, PHP, Python, Java exposing DOM manipulation together with XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You need XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="extra" select="document('doc2.xml')//Row/node()"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row"/>
    </Rowset>
  </Rowsets>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
  <row>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$extra"/>
  </row>
</xsl:template>
```